# Sort NSArray to a particular sequence using an NSComparisonResult

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, comparator

I'm trying to sort my arrays with a particular sequence using an `NSComparisonResult`. I'm unable to figure out how to achieve the sequence I'm wanting.

I'm trying to weight Emojis towards the top (sequence of Emojis doesn't matter), followed by A-Z letters with giving a weight towards lowercase before uppercase, followed by numbers, followed by punctuation, then by symbols, and whatever else after that I dont care about at this point. I've gotten pretty close so far, but am still coming up short with what I want.

The sequence I'm trying to achieve would look like this as the output:

```
("\Ud83d\Ude03",
a,
A,
aa,
aA,
ab,
aB,
a1,
A1,
1,
01,
11,
001,
0001,
1001,
"#",
"#a",
"#1",
"$12",
"$0012")
```

Based upon this array as the input:

```
@[ @"a", @"aA", @"aa", @"A", @"aB", @"11", @"1001", @"ab", @"001", @"01", 
   @"a1", @"A1", @"", @"0001", @"1", @"#", @"$12", @"$0012", @"#a", @"#1" ];
```

But this is the output I'm getting:

```
("\Ud83d\Ude03",
a,
A,
aA,
aa,
aB,
ab,
a1,
A1,
0001,
001,
01,
1,
1001,
11,
"#a",
"#1",
"$0012",
"$12",
"#")
```

Code:

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArray:(NSArray *)input
{
    NSArray *newArray = [input sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
    {
        NSString *nameOne = obj1;
        NSString *nameTwo = obj2;

        NSString *startOne;
        NSString *startTwo;

        NSInteger currentIndex = 0;
        NSInteger maxIndex = (nameOne.length < nameTwo.length) ? nameOne.length : nameTwo.length;

        NSCharacterSet *decimalDigitCharSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];

        NSCharacterSet *punctuationCharSet = [NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet];

        NSCharacterSet *symbolCharSet = [NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet];

        NSMutableCharacterSet *nonPriorityCharSet = [[NSMutableCharacterSet alloc]init];

        [nonPriorityCharSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:punctuationCharSet];
        [nonPriorityCharSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:symbolCharSet];

        do
        {
            if (currentIndex < maxIndex)
            {
                startOne = [nameOne substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(currentIndex, 1)];
                startTwo  = [nameTwo substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(currentIndex, 1)];
                currentIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (nameOne.length == nameTwo.length)
                {
                    return NSOrderedSame;
                }
                else
                {
                    return (nameOne.length < nameTwo.length) ? NSOrderedAscending : NSOrderedDescending;
                }
            }
        }
        while ([startOne isEqualToString:startTwo]);
        {
            NSRange rangeOne = [startOne rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonPriorityCharSet];
            NSRange rangeTwo = [startTwo rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonPriorityCharSet];

            if (rangeOne.length > 0 || rangeTwo.length > 0)
            {
                return (rangeOne.length > 0) ? NSOrderedDescending : NSOrderedAscending;
            }

            NSRange decimalRangeOne = [startOne rangeOfCharacterFromSet:decimalDigitCharSet];
            NSRange decimalRangeTwo = [startTwo rangeOfCharacterFromSet:decimalDigitCharSet];

            if (decimalRangeOne.length > 0 || decimalRangeTwo.length > 0)
            {
                if (decimalRangeOne.length == decimalRangeTwo.length)
                {
                    return (startOne.intValue > startTwo.intValue) ? NSOrderedDescending : NSOrderedAscending;
                }
                else if (decimalRangeOne.length > decimalRangeTwo.length)
                {
                    return NSOrderedDescending;
                }
                else if (decimalRangeTwo.length > decimalRangeOne.length)
                {
                    return NSOrderedAscending;
                }
            }
        }

        return  [nameOne localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:nameTwo];
   }];

    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started well. But you didn't properly check for all the rules that you have set. I have created some categories based on you rules, and sort using them.

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArray:(NSArray *)input
{
    __block id blocksafeSelf = self;

    NSArray *newArray = [input sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSString *nameOne = obj1;
        NSString *nameTwo = obj2;

        NSInteger currentIndex = 0;
        unichar charOne = [nameOne characterAtIndex:0];
        unichar charTwo = [nameTwo characterAtIndex:0];

        short maxLength = MIN(nameOne.length, nameTwo.length);

        do {
            charOne = [nameOne characterAtIndex:currentIndex];
            charTwo = [nameTwo characterAtIndex:currentIndex];
            currentIndex ++;
        }
        while (charOne == charTwo && currentIndex < maxLength);

        short oneCategory = [blocksafeSelf getCharCategory:charOne];
        short twoCategory = [blocksafeSelf getCharCategory:charTwo];

        if (oneCategory != twoCategory) {
            return oneCategory > twoCategory;
        }
        else if (oneCategory != 1) {
            if (nameOne.length != nameTwo.length) {
                return nameOne.length > nameTwo.length;
            }
            else {
                return charOne > charTwo;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (nameOne.length != nameTwo.length) {
                return nameOne.length > nameTwo.length;
            }
            else {
                oneCategory = [blocksafeSelf getLetterCategory:charOne];
                twoCategory = [blocksafeSelf getLetterCategory:charTwo];

                if (oneCategory == twoCategory) {
                    return charOne > charTwo;
                }
                else {
                    unichar tempCharOne = oneCategory == 7 ? charOne + 32 : charOne;
                    unichar tempCharTwo = twoCategory == 7 ? charTwo + 32 : charTwo;

                    if (tempCharOne != tempCharTwo) {
                        return tempCharOne > tempCharTwo;
                    }
                    else {
                        return oneCategory > twoCategory;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return  [nameOne localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:nameTwo];
    }];

    return newArray;
}

- (short)getCharCategory:(unichar)character {

    if (character > 255) {     // emoji
        return 0;
    }

    NSCharacterSet *letterCaseCharSet = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
    if  ([letterCaseCharSet characterIsMember:character]) return 1;

    NSCharacterSet *decimalDigitCharSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
    if  ([decimalDigitCharSet characterIsMember:character]) return 2;

    NSCharacterSet *punctuationCharSet = [NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet];
    if  ([punctuationCharSet characterIsMember:character]) return 3;

    NSCharacterSet *symbolCharSet = [NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet];
    if  ([symbolCharSet characterIsMember:character]) return 4;

    return 5;

}

- (short)getLetterCategory:(unichar)character {

    NSCharacterSet *lowerCaseCharSet = [NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet];
    if  ([lowerCaseCharSet characterIsMember:character]) return 6;

    return 7;
}
```

Comment: Is the check: `character > 255` saying it's above the range of ascii, but it could still be something that's not an emoji?

Comment: Yes. You're right about that. Here's an answer about detecting emoji: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14472163/4815066

Comment: Yes. But being a bit more than a year old, it may not work properly with the new emoji in iOS 8.3.