# Offset UITextField - Emoji-layout

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to offset UITextField whenever the keyboard is active, it works well, until I tried the Emoji-layout. Is there a way to detect the type of Keyboard-input, so I can find out the height-difference?
Thanks
 [image]

Comment: You can use textfield delegates to detect if user has typed in an emoji. See [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329110/detect-if-a-user-has-typed-an-emoji-character-in-uitextview).

Comment: @EICaptain I believe his issue is not to set the offset (He is doing that with simple text input). He is having trouble with handling emoji inputs due to which he wants to detect **type of input** from the keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your help, i have found the answer:
I was using this line :

```
if let keyboardSize = (notifcation.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().size{
```

I changed to the key-value of **notifcation.userInfo** to **UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey**, and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyboard notifications

```
func getKeyboardHeight() {
    let defaultCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    defaultCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillChangeFrame:", name: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillChangeFrame(notification : NSNotification){
    let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    let keyboardheight = keyboardFrame.height
}
```

And from the obtained height you can adjust the textfield's frame.
 see the images. 
image 1 before emoji is selected.
[image]

image 2 after emoji is selected

[image]

Comment: That's code to show keyboard appearance notification, not to detect whether emojis are being typed or not. If you have any queries regarding the question, Ask the OP via comments

Comment: You can get the keyboard height and adjust the textfield frame dynamically

Comment: He is already doing that. His issue is that he is having problems when user types in emoji due to which he wants to detect **Type of input**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification/UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` observers, use the **`UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification`** observer, that is fired of each event: Keyboard hiding, keyboard showing and keyboard changing frame.

**Like this:**

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardAction), name: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
```